# Exclude specific folder with images from being cached by Apache?

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, cache-control

How can I exclude a specific folder that has a number of PNG images in it from being cached by Apache?

Here is my cache-control.conf

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>

Header unset Pragma
Header unset ETag
FileETag None

<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public"
</FilesMatch>

</IfModule>
```

**EDIT:** I should have clarified that for security reasons I have `AllowOverride None` in my httpd.conf for my virtual hosts.

Before I tried placing .htaccess file with the following content into the images folder but later realized that I had `AllowOverride None` set.

```
<filesMatch "\.(png)$">
    ExpiresDefault A0
    Header set Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
</filesMatch>
```

Is there any way to do this on a main Apache config level?

Thank you!

Comment: Just added a few findings with `AllowOverride None`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this by turning On AllowOverride for that specific folder:

`<Directory "/path_to_my_directory">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>`

in my VirtualHost, so my `.htaccess` file started to work only for that specifc folder.